# How to download any file coming from sever in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting some file path from sever using API, but here I want to download those  file if click on them.
I am using react js-file download package.
what I have code so far is below.

```
        downloadFileforUser =(path)=>{
         var data = (baseUrl+'/SurveyImages/'+path )
         fileDownload(data, path);

 }
```

it is downloading file but I can not read those file such pdf, jpg,png,
please help me
I am new to Reactjs
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Comment: I  am still facing issue, could not resolve so far..

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to React. However, you can use the download attribute on the anchor  element to tell the browser to download the file.

```
<a href='your file path' download>Click to download</a>
```

Comment: hi, it is not downloading  just opening in new tab

Comment: but here I want to download file

Comment: ` <a href={baseUrl+'/SurveyImages/'+link} download>{link}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to reactjs but it's javascript related so you can take a look at this sample

In mozilla docs example:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();

var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };

var myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg', myInit);

    fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
      return response.blob();
    }).then(function(myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
```

You can read full code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Do I need make API call ?

Comment: It's depend. this code is using for make api call and download a file