# How to download the file from server location in react Js

Tags: reactjs

On below onclick event I am hitting the API to get the filepath and then passing that filepath to download method----

```
onClick={event => 
                    { event.preventDefault();this.handleDownloadDoc('downloadAPI')}}>
```

Download method is :-

```
handleDownloadDoc = (function (fileName) {    
    var a = window.createElement("a"); 
    window.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(fileName),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "text/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

with above code I am getting error as does not create Element.
Please help to fix this up.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Answer (score 8):

This is the example for download a file from server:-

```
import React from 'react';
import './download.css';

class DownloadFile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    downloadEmployeeData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/employees/download')
            .then(response => {
                response.blob().then(blob => {
                    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'employees.json';
                    a.click();
                });
                //window.location.href = response.url;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <h1>Download File using React App</h1>
                <h3>Download Employee Data using Button</h3>
                <button onClick={this.downloadEmployeeData}>Download</button>
                <p/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default DownloadFile;
```

For more reference you can go through [This link](https://www.roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-react/)

Comment: can we use something else instead of fetch

Comment: Yes we can use axios also.

Comment: Actually i tried fetch where I passed the location of server where the file is kept to download at some location but on click I am getting redirected to application again and file is not downloaded

Comment: Hi there I have used your solution to download files of type .xlsx, .png, .pdf, .csv, .docx, .txt but I've got empty files.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need IIFE to execute the code.
2. You don't need to create arrow function inside the render method.

Working code below and [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lumiere-4xnt1):-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleDownloadDoc = fileName => e => {
    // Downloads the file
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = `${fileName}.txt`;
    const blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], { type: "text/plain" });
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);

    // Opens in new window
    // const blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], { type: "text/plain" });
    // const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // window.open(fileURL);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleDownloadDoc("downloadApi")}>
          Download
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: with this code nothing working on click of filename link in UI

Comment: If you run open [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lumiere-4xnt1) and click on download button, it will download file with name `downloadApi.txt`.

Comment: The second code I have commented if you want to open in new window. For you case you don't need to un-comment the `open in new window` code.

Comment: No I only commented to view what's it opening and when I tried it giving blob: soemvalue and when uncommenting it doing nothing.

Comment: May you have to enable downloading from page. You have to give permission to open a file because for me the same code or codesandbox is working

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([_response?.data]),);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download',Report.csv, // File name with type
                );
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

**Try this one.**