# Is it possible to download file from external url using anchor tag in react?

Tags: reactjs

usecase:
when use clicks on "Download File", an external file associated with it should get downloaded to user's matchine.

I tried :
1.

```
<a href={downloadfileUrl} download={downloadfileUrl}>
        <div className="filename" data-testid="download-link-filename">
          Download file
        </div>
      </a>
```

2. 

```
<Link
        // href={downloadfileUrl}
        target="_blank"
        to={{ pathname: {downloadfileUrl} }}
        download
      >
        Download Template
      </Link>
```

Tried above with many combinations. It's not working, I can see "Download file" hyperlink on UI but it does not download the file when I click on it.
Can someone suggest any solutions

Comment: have you tried `<a href={downloadfileUrl} download>`  ?

Comment: Yes. Anchor tag's download doesn't works for external urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function and replace your url in fetch it might works!

```
downloadEmployeeData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/employees/download')
        .then(response => {
            response.blob().then(blob => {
                let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'employees.json';
                a.click();
            });
            //window.location.href = response.url;
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt be doing direct DOM manipulation in react

Comment: ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830976/how-to-download-the-file-from-server-location-in-react-js

Comment: This did not work for my URL, it does not take the fetched url of type string/undefiened

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be the `react-download-link` package :

1. install with `npm install --save react-download-link`
2. Include with `import DownloadLink from "react-download-link";`
3. Use :

```
<DownloadLink
    label="Save"
    filename="myfile.txt"
    exportFile={() => "My cached data"}
/>
```

package official [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-download-link)

Comment: this makes the file content overrided by "My cached data". I should see the data which is in the provided filename

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import axios from 'axios';
  
  <a
    href={downloadFileUrl}
    onClick={() => axios.get(downloadFileUrl)}
  >
    Download File
  </a>
```