# How to download a file(.jpg/.txt/.pdf/.mp4) from url in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to download file from absolute url in react js.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Comment: @EvgenySkarlat i didnt find my answer there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)

Comment: nope :( @Kundan

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React Router, use the below given code.

```
<Link to="/document/mydocument.pdf" target="_blank" download>Download</Link>
```

Where `/document/mydocument.pdf` is inside your public folder.

Comment: This works if i give relative url, but in my case im using absolute url like 

https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this with `download` attribute.

```
<a href="path to file" download> Download </a>
```

Comment: This is redirecting to other tab instead of downloading

Comment: Please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763856/10971575

Comment: i didnt find my answer there

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you could create an endpoint which will give you the file with the correct headers. When you create the endpoint, look for Content-Disposition and Content-Type. This will trigger an automatic and consistent download through-out all browsers.

The problem is that front-end code regarding download and the download attribute can behave differently depending on the browser. If you are not able to serve them through an endpoint, I think you will always need to keep the trade-offs in mind like inconsistent behavior through different browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Iborghs. Yeah, creating an endpoint seems to be ideal solution for this.