# Trying to download pdf from react native webview

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I can't seem to get this to work i know. the "onFileDownload={ ( { nativeEvent: { downloadUrl } } ) => {" has been added and i need my own code to make this work. I tried to use expo file system and expo sharing to get this to download but it's not working. all i want is that when they download a pdf instead of a preview they can share the document or save it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code i tried to make it work but failed (the alert function works but then nothing happens):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, View, Platform, PermissionsAndroid, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
//sharing and download
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function App() {
let [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = React.useState(null);

let openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
{downloadUrl},
${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/pdf.pdf,
{},
);

const { uri, status } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
// setSelectedImage({ localUri: uri });
Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
};

let openShareDialogAsync = async () => {
if (!(await Sharing.isAvailableAsync())) {
alert(Uh oh, sharing isn't available on your platform);
return;
}

Sharing.shareAsync(selectedImage.localUri);
};

// if (selectedImage !== null) {
// return (
// 
// 
// Share this
// 
// 
// );
// }

return (
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<WebView
style={{ flex: 1 }}
source={{ uri: 'http://www.pdf995.com/' }}
onFileDownload={ ( { nativeEvent: { downloadUrl } } ) => {

        Alert.alert(
          "Documents",
          "Do you wish to download and share this document",
          [
            {
              text: "Download",
              onPress: () => {openImagePickerAsync}
            },
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
              style: "cancel"
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );}
      } />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I took the code from expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@trinet/sharing
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm really stuck

Comment: Hi, interesting, was there an error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience, in my case, it was due to some wrong header config, [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) inline instead of an attachment, so what happened is that inline attribute makes it render the content in the web page whereas attachment sees a file and tries to download it without previewing.

Add this in the header config of the file on the server and you will be file.
Credits to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50695407/4434417) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/4434417)