# Material-UI: how to download a file when clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I know how to download a file when clicking a button using html

```
<a href="./abcf32x.pdf" download="How-to-download-file.pdf">
    <button>Download File</button>
</a>
```

But using Material-UI component how can I do this

I have the following component

```
<div>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="#ffa726"
    size="large"
    startIcon={<GetAppIcon />}
  >
    Download Sample Method File
  </Button>
</div>
```

[image]

Now I want to download a file whose url is `http://localhost:8000/static/sample_method.py`

I don't want to open the link in browser and then do save as, rather it should get downloaded directly.

Answer (score 7):

You already had your answer in the question. Instead of declaring `a` element with an `href` and `download` attribute using JSX syntax. Create that `a` element and click it programmatically:

```js
function App() {
  const onDownload = () => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = `download.txt`;
    link.href = "./download.txt";
    link.click();
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={onDownload} variant="contained" color="primary">
      Download
    </Button>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66811401/reactjs-material-ui-how-to-download-a-file-on-clicking-a-button]

Comment: this only works when the content-description has attachment

Comment: Do you know why this is not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666135/trouble-downloading-a-file-from-react-failed-no-file @NearHuscarl

Comment: @325 if you're using CRA, try putting the asset (the file to be downloaded) in the public folder

Comment: What is CRA? @NearHuscarl

Comment: ```import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function DownloadFile() {
  const onDownload = () => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = `testDownload.txt`;
    link.href = "./files/testDownload.txt";
    link.click();
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={onDownload} size="small" color="primary">
      Download
    </Button>
  );
} ``` @NearHuscarl

Comment: @325 create-react-app. Are you using webpack? can you put your code on codesandbox or github so everybody can see and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I made a folder called "files" within my public folder. I placed my testDownload.txt in the folder, but when I click my Download button, I still get "Failed - No file"

Comment: https://github.com/dte324/machine/tree/dte324-patch-1 @NearHuscarl

Comment: It work on Chrome on MacOS but it doesn't in Chrome on iPhone while the simple `a` tag with the `download` attribute works.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/), I thinks this will work, and in case of using nextjs, don't forget to put that file inside the public folder

```html
<Button variant='contained' component="label">
    <a href="/files/CV.pdf" target="_blank" download>
         Download csv
    </a>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inbuilt href prop along with the download prop of [MUI Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#prop-href) like this:

```
<Button
variant="contained"
color="info"
endIcon={<FiDownload />}
href="/resume.pdf"
download
>
 Resume
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onClick` event handler of the button to get the event callback and utilize the following code from the following link to download the file.

https://codesource.io/how-to-download-file-in-javascript/

Comment: unfortunately it opens the download link in the browser (eg: image) instead of saving it

Comment: It should be a full download link, then it shall download it.

Comment: It shall not. The link might be a link to page. See this example here to download an image. https://codesandbox.io/s/66811401reactjs-material-ui-how-to-download-a-file-on-clicking-a-button-forked-9y4ej?file=/index.js

Comment: I think it has something to do with the url. For your url works. Can you check this url -- `https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/dde881ee7846ed21119d52f60dea7053`

Comment: Yes, I did wget https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/dde881ee7846ed21119d52f60dea7053.jpg and output is in next comment. Server do not allow the image to be download,

Comment: StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {255, 216, 255, 224...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Link: <https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dde881ee7846ed21119d52f60dea7053.jpg>; rel="canonical"
             ...
                    <https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dde881ee7846ed21119d52f60dea7053.jpg>; rel="canonical"], 
                    [Content-Disposition, inline; filename="dde881ee7846ed21119d52f60dea7053.jpeg"]

Comment: ok, i got it. Currently i used `js-file-download` and `axios`. it downloads the file irrespective of the headers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002765/2897115

Comment: Awesome. !! what headers did you used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the

> file-saver

package to download your file.

To install it, run:

> npm i file-saver

Then you can call the saveAs function from the package by writing:

```
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
      "example.pdf"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first argument is the URL to download and the 2nd argument is the file name of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the download parameter to the Button element as in the example below:

```
<div>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="#ffa726"
    size="large"
    startIcon={<GetAppIcon />}
    download
  >
    Download Sample Method File
  </Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is uploaded from UI then we have to download in the following way

**uploaded file:**

```
const data = {
  lastModified: 1701069121191,
  lastModifiedDate: Mon Nov 27 2023 12:42:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {},
  name: "Template_v2(1).xlsx",
  size: 91827,
  type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

**download:**

```
const onDownload = d => {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.download = d.name
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(d) // method creates a string containing a URL representing the object
    link.click()
}

<Button onClick={onDownload(data)} variant="contained" color="primary">Download</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct Material UI way is:

```
import {Button, Link} from '@mui/material'

<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="#ffa726"
    size="large"
    startIcon={<GetAppIcon />}
    component={Link}
    href="./abcf32x.pdf"
    download="How-to-download-file.pdf"
>
    Download Sample Method File
</Button>
```