# How to read and download binary file in react/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have base64 data of a file coming from API to react and need to read and download this file in it's actual form
`PDF , doc , ..`
or link the download action to a button

Comment: This is probable duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Comment: not duplicated .. he has a url but in my case only binary data of the file

Comment: By binary you mean base64?

Comment: yes and i want to return it to it's actual form //Note: the extension of the file can be pdf || xls || .docx ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a download="filename.png" href="data:image/png;base64,foo...">Download</a>
```

Comment: didn't work ,, just downloaded unknown file {the binary file itself} i want to get it back as pdf or whatever it's actual form was