# How to download excel file that is downloadable from server in react

Tags: reactjs, excel, file

I am facing an issue that the file when you hit the URL in browser it auto download but in postman return characters

response from postman

[image]

how is it possible to make it downloadable from react? when hit the URL it just return the weird characters response.
I want when click a button just to look like this

[image: the response that I want]

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50695012/7409146

Comment: @AntoninRiche i have an auth token i should send in header what should i do ?

Comment: another soluce https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940307/7409146, axios let you provide headers