# Downloading a pdf in react with a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an anchor tag (`a href`) defined with the path for my resume. The resume is in the public folder in a folder but when i click on the "My CV" button all i get back is Failed no file?

[image: The anchor tag and button]

[image: files & folders]

Comment: did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Comment: Maybe try `./resume/myCV.pdf`?

Answer (score 1):

just checked on my code, seems you need to place a tag inside the button not above:

```
<button>
    <a
        href='/pathToPdf.pdf'
        target='_blank'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
    >
        RESUME
    </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see remove {} from href attribute because it's not JavaScript code
then in download meta-attribute you should put your file extenstion ".pdf"

```
   <button>    
     <a
     href="./public/file.pdf"
     download="mycv.pdf">
     Save
     </a>    
    </button>
```