# How can i download a pdf file that comes from a .NET Api with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, typescript

[image]

I have a CreatePdf function on my Api an it returns a pdf file.When ı click a download button on a react page, it send a request to this function and trigger it.I can see the response like this image.But I could not manage to download it when I click the button.
Also if i open this response on a new blank page, it automatically download the pdf.But I can not download it with button.

Comment: This can help you.
Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor tag with download option..

```
<Button> 
<a href={"download pdf link"} download="PdfFileName">
   Download
 </a>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getPdfDownload = () => {
const url = "YOUR_URL";
axios
  .get(url, {
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    headers: {
      Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem("AUTH_TOKEN") || "",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/pdf",
    },
  })
  .then((response:any) => {

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'FILENAME.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Error", err);

  })
```

};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).