# Pdf download in react directly from server

Tags: reactjs

I want to download pdf directly from api response but the format that i am getting from api response is this :

> %PDF-1.7 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >>
> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type
> /Pages /Kids [6 0 R 9 0 R ] /Count 2 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R
> /Font <<  /F1 8 0 R /F2 11 0 R
>
> > > /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
> > > endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Producer (��dompdf 1.2.1 + CPDF) /CreationDate
> > > (D:20221029062939+00'00') /ModDate (D:20221029062939+00'00')
> > > endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R
> > > endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 189 >> stream x�u��J�@F�<�W���3���"��N,B2w�$˾�R����;�[HB`���І�t�=V1)�����s�XR�v�ի�:&v�9g<>KHAa�^S����Mc�us<| ��)lef2B��m�c̸&(Y�;_R.Ѵ��Zk�ZƐ�~��ˀ�Y������n�%��|/QO�J���P� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Page /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 10 0 R endobj 10 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 949 >> stream x��W�n�F}�WHk��K��$N�)�XA�>0��&B�I���wIi�2d]A��Μ���g�IΡ�Yߞ   ����?*͸�p�2�1�8��7�7g$٫��3g8�`��+�������
> > > �?υV/���{�\�JZ&�Dv�4�{���c�͗�YɄ h~_mʶ�ќ3��f���8ôt?
> > > o6��ɜ��4�s�����6=�e��D`VP%{�m�|��XV]���c$<S�*�"g�ͤ�\�r����t.Qi��=��N �r�!��]?Q���{�bwpĻ2o��ϗ0�)i�tfI�if    �1�KG@��b��ME�?���mK��cg���DMfB̸F _g�2E\��4������>=f� h:%�QU���T|���"��z�Y���ͫrP�$ӹ&�fD�j�[H/xWn+\5��q��?l�Э0m�{L��? I7��0�������N�3KBN3;*�-��}�]���MB�栄��9һF*�&Hf��$-V�r5�3�-Vk�GzÜn�=����5�訪,(��Zl�i�bӠ����<7��8]���$A�L tG��4i�S�I3 ��%�?e<�QsQ�Y�\[3V�4(-��@a/��̓>yUĬ�x۹�[Xg��w��V�����*��a���jUǦyIQs<ϓ�vU-������}��H�e�L��'<N���!˱#��^ge���۪�v�൵�:�/�E��|y.�����3|�`�W@r����c�ϋ���x��"�I�QIj�����j�w��t�]p�X�*/�g�e�p�\�>����%ʜ7�������w���$#��8)աk��Ep̓*��ŎH�N��R��+����*�ɕ�X�����
> > > &I52���\�z̷�����oc��+||=��ž�� �pM�'��s���]�X�$�ԭk�d����I
> > > endstream endobj 11 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2
> > > /BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
> > > endobj xref 0 12 0000000000 65535 f  0000000009 00000 n  0000000074 00000 n  0000000120 00000 n  0000000291 00000 n  0000000320 00000 n
> > > 0000000469 00000 n  0000000572 00000 n  0000000833 00000 n  0000000940
> > > 00000 n  0000001044 00000 n  0000002066 00000 n  trailer << /Size 12
> > > /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R
> > > /ID[<71468b7d13dde79b89173b27b85d8251><71468b7d13dde79b89173b27b85d8251>]
> > > startxref 2179 %%EOF

So any one has idea how to download this kind of file directly!

I tried using

```
fileDownload(apiCall.data, `customer-${payload.customer_id}.pdf`);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)

Comment: I am getting encoded pdf in response which would not always be same so anchor tag doesnt solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You want to download the PDF to the user. Just put a anchor tag in the template, so the download can be done with a link.

```
<a href="customer-${payload.customer_id}.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

*Note:* It seems you are using the React File Download (npm). This is to download a file (data) to use in javascript. I suppose the file should be downloaded to the user.

Comment: I want this to be downloaded directly from api like this : try {
      api(`bills/printcreateAction`, payload, "postWithoutToken").then(
        (apiCall) => {
          if (apiCall.status !== 200) {
            Toast.error(apiCall.data.error);
            return;
          } else {
            Toast.success(apiCall.data.message);
            fileDownload(apiCall.data, `customer-${payload.customer_id}.pdf`);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ Error: err });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You want to download the PDF to the user. It can be done with a simple call.

```
window.location = "<URL computed from javacript>"
```