# how to automatically download pdf from url without opening it in browser ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an automatic download after I finish creating a pdf document in the backend and return a url to it in the frontend.
I don't want the document to open in the browser from the url, but to start downloading automatically.

I tried to create a fake <a> link in DOM with href and download attributes and then download, but it's open the document in the browser when tried to action click().
This is what I have right now but it downloads a pdf document that fails when opening it.

```
const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

const link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = fileURL;

link.download = "FileName.pdf";

link.click();
```

Comment: you can use a `response.download()` method return from the controller method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)

Comment: In the solution proposed there it also downloads a pdf file that cannot be opened

Comment: If the backend is generating the file and returning a url, then why does the code go through the extra steps of fetching the file and creating a blob?

Comment: The pdf is uploaded to temporary storage so that the client can download it, this is the solution I found to automatically download a pdf, i tried to just make fake <a\> element and add href and download properties but it's opening the pdf file in a new tab when i starts the click() function of <a element.