# Getting download error while using fetch to download PDF in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, material-ui

I am trying to create a button that downloads a PDF in my React component. I have tried several different ways to achieve with no luck. The code below is the closest I've gotten. If I click the button, the pdf downloads but when I open the download it has an error "Failed to load PDF document."

Any ideas how to fix?

```
  const onButtonDownloadSales = () => {
    fetch('TermsEquipSales.pdf').then(res => {
      res.blob().then(blob => {
        const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
        let alink = document.createElement('a');
        alink.href = fileURL;
        alink.setAttribute('download', 'TermsEquipSales.pdf')
        document.body.appendChild(alink)
        // alink.download = 'TermsEquipSales.pdf'
        alink.click()
        alink.parentNode.removeChild(alink)
      })
    })
  }


 <Box>
     <button onClick={onButtonDownloadSales}>
       Standard Terms and Conditions for the Sale of Equipment
     </button>
 </Box>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new blob from an existing blob? Why not just use `createObjectURL(blob)`?

Comment: I doubt very much that `'TermsEquipSales.pdf'` is the correct URL. Where is the file located? Is it bundled with your project and if so, how?

Comment: Please try to follow these steps to download the file [Link to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965930/15119646)

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA OP's code already looks exactly the same

Comment: @Phil thank you for looking at my code. I had tried createObjectURL(blob) with the same outcome. I am just desperate lol. My file is located in my src folder, should I move it?

Comment: Why bother with `fetch` at all? Just put your file in the `public` folder and use `<a href="/TermsEquipSales.pdf" download>`

Comment: Thanks Phil! I moved my pdf's folder and it's working! Thank you for the realization