# Problems with opening blob files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

Can't understand why it doesn't display the Blob file. the code is:

```
openBlob = fileBuffer => {
const file = new Blob([fileBuffer], { type: "image/bmp" }); // You could also add the MIME type here as { type: "application/pdf" }
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
console.log("fileURL" + fileURL)
window.open(fileURL, "_blank_");
 };

render() {
const archivioItems = this.state.archivio.map((archivio, i) => {
  return (
    <tr key={archivio.hash_referto}>
      <td>{archivio.tipo_esame}</td>
      <td>{archivio.data_esame}</td>
      <td>
        <Tab icon={<AssignmentIcon />}              
          className="tab"
           onClick={() => this.openBlob(archivio.uri)}></Tab>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
})
```

It opens a new page as a pdf, but then returns an alert with "It's not possible to open the pdf document" (even it's a pdf document). And more, is there a way to open any kind of document?

Comment: hey, some clarification needed. the `achivio.uri` is a buffer or just uri to a file ?

Comment: The uri to that document was too big so i stored it as a Blob in the database

Answer (score 0):

When using Blob make sure the passed argument to the constructor is a file buffer.
As clarified from the comments you save the files as blobs in the database, assuming `archivio.uri` is already a blob(as said in the comment). then its not necessary to reapply blob over it just pass the data itself to `URL.createObjectUrl`. if thats not the case and the database item is not a blob make sure you read the file content from uri first then converting the file data to blob and presenting it to the user.

you can read more here about a method to load a uri file then converting it to a blob:
[load uri and convert to blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url/11901662)

***UPDATE***

**case #1**:

```
openBlob = (fileBuffer) => { //file buffer is already a buffer
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileBuffer);
console.log("fileURL" + fileURL)
window.open(fileURL, "_blank_");
 };
```

**case #2**:

fileBuffer is not a **buffer** but a URI to a file.
notice that this operation is **asynchronous** because there is reading operation of a file from remote URI.

```
openBlob = (fileUri) => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader()
    const data = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUri)
    .then(function(buffer){
        const blob = new Blob(buffer,{type:".....what ever is your type..."})
        console.log("File Blob:")
        console.log(blob)
        window.open(blob,"_blank_")
    })
}
```

Comment: @mikerug88 updated the answer as desired, provided two cases, one in which the input of the function is already a file blob, and the second one in which there is process reading a remote URI file converting it to blob then presenting it to the user.

Comment: Thank you, really, but it says "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

Comment: typeof fileBuffer = object

Comment: The reason could be:  i settled the type of the attribute in the database as a Blob, but when i store the uri in the database, i don't turn it into a Buffer. maybe?

Comment: 1. the URL object is from the window object if not found try window.URL.createObjectUrl.


2. if the desired function reads a URL from the database then case 2 will match your job if the database URI stores a buffer then case 1 will do it. if settled in DB as blob then make sure you store it as a blob.

Comment: @mikerug88 have a notice that i updated solution 2 , making a blob from a uri requires a stream(file content) to create a blob from.

Comment: in that solution data is not used anywhere

Comment: @mikerug88 mistyped , corrected in the latest update

Comment: I decode it now when i store the uri in the database:  
var decoded = dataUriToBuffer(assetUrl)
console.log("decoded", Buffer.isBuffer(decoded))
the answer of the console.log is true, so it's stored as a buffer, but when i try to open it as a url
openBlob = (fileBuffer) => { 
    console.log("fileBuffer", Buffer.isBuffer(fileBuffer))
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileBuffer);
    console.log("fileURL" + fileURL)
    window.open(fileURL, "_blank_");
     };
the Buffer.isBuffer says it's not a buffer anymore, but with typeof it says it's an object