# Displaying file in web page using AJAX and Spring Boot

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, file-io

I am building a REST API in Spring Boot for uploading and fetching file from the server, I want to upload various types of file that can either be text,image,audio,video,etc..

While uploading there is no problem, but when I want to display the file on my web page, on content is appearing, but I am getting the data from the server as a raw data.

I want to put that data into URL.createObjectURL() and then redirect to the URL which is generated.

There are some screenshots which I am uploading.

This is the data when I do console.log(response);
[image]

The code which I am using for AJAX

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("qualifiedFilePath", "E://files/test.png");

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/callTransaction/file",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "processData": false,
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    "contentType": false,
    "Accept": "image/png",
    "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], {
        "type": "image/png"
    }));
    console.log(objectURL);
});
```

I get the URL:
blob:http://localhost:8080/81c9fbde-5e84-400e-8d92-5da6fc02c7ef

Output:

[image]

The Source Code in Spring Boot:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path="/file")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> loadFile(@RequestPart("qualifiedFilePath") String qualifiedFilePath, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return ctbl.loadFile(qualifiedFilePath,request);
}
```

BusinessLogic:

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> loadFile(String qualifiedFilePath, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        Resource file=null;
        if(qualifiedFilePath==null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(file,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        try {
            file=ctdi.loadFile(qualifiedFilePath);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(file,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        if(file==null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(file,HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
          String contentType = null;
            try {
                contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(file,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }

            if(contentType == null) {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
                                .body(file);
    }
```

DAO:

```
@Override
public Resource loadFile(String qualifiedFilePath) throws MalformedURLException {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(qualifiedFilePath);
    Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
    return resource;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time to answer since the question was posted, but the solution to it has been discovered.

It has a very simple solution.

I used the program logic from the CalliCoder webiste[the link is attached below], by using this I was able to store files, view files and download them too, they have given a very nice explanation of the program and how to do it.

By using this we can make a URL(endpoint) by which we can access the file we are approaching for, they too have given an example for accessing the file.

They have made a web-based front-end in which they are trying to upload files, but the module for displaying the file/downloading the file in front-end is missing.

Yes, We can just copy the URL(endpoint) in the browser and it starts displaying/playing the file.

If we want to use URL.createObjectURL() for making a temporary and local URL for the same source, then we can do like this:

```
URL.createObjectURL(await fetch("URL(endpoint)").then(r => r.blob()));
```

This example is taken from Stackoverflow[The link is attached bellow]

References:

- [CalliCoder](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url)