# Upload local blob image url to php

Tags: javascript, php, image, upload, blob

I have a blob image URL in my localhost (looks like "blob:http://localhost/1d795687-b478-4edf-9b3d-8dda768b9d9f") and I want to pick up this file and upload it to PHP using JavaScript.

[image: Network section that shows the blob image]

I just want to know how to get this image as a file.

Comment: Use the original blob that you used to create the url, otherwise you would have to use a workaround like `fetch()`-ing the url and get the blob, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url

Comment: 'fetch()' worked as well. I got my URL blob, passed to fetch(), it gave me a blob object, then I did a new file object with the blob and uploaded it to PHP. Thank You!

Comment: Note you dont need to create a new file object you can just send the blob, `File` is just a special type of `Blob`

Comment: I just checked it out and it really works with just a blob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob())` and it gave me a blob object with my image stored in local blob URL.

Code:

```
let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
var data = new FormData();
data.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg');
```

Then, just send `data` to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should sent the file as formData. Then you save it directly as a blob in your server. You can use code like

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append(key, blobImage);
Make backend api call with formdata
```

Comment: Can i pass the blob URL in "blobImage"?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the blob URL in blobImage