# Is it possible to web scrape a blob URL from a website in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, blob, bloburls

I am trying to extract a CSV file which is stored in a blob URL in this domain using beautiful soup: https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/exports-by-country

Here's my code:

```
exports  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get(BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/exports-by-country').text,\
        'html.parser').find_all(download="csvData.csv"))))
```

What I got was an exception and NO blob link in the href. The blob url does exist when I inspect the html on my browser:
[image: and here the exception i received]

I decided to just do a get request for the blob url itself instead of scraping it since the href does not show the blob url but this exception appears:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'blob:https://worldpopulationreview.com/850ac28e-9cd9-46b6-9423-e96a0bd7e938'
```

Is there a way to web scrape blob URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These blob URLs are created only in the browser, usually with Javascript, they don't exist on the server at all. So you cannot download them with `requests`.

You could use a Javascript script in the browser console to get the content, here is an example on how to fetch the blob URL in Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410044/

If you need to do this automatically, you can possibly create a [userscript](https://openuserjs.org/about/Userscript-Beginners-HOWTO) to do it or use an automation tool like [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) to click th download link automatically.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I used Selenium : https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ . If you want to automate chrome then you will need to download the chrome driver : https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started .