# Getting thumbnails of images in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There's a site with 10 or more images, lets say

```
<div class="container"><img src="some_URL"></div>
```

I want to generate thumbnails to them to save images into extension's storage, so that I can view them without offline or without heavy traffic. That site does not allow cross-origin use of images, so atm I'm trying to use the next "algorithm":

1. Include a following script (include2page.js) to the page.
2. Start cycle from 0 to number of images on the page.
3. Get the visible position and size of an image.
4. Scroll page to it, send coordinates via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` to extension's background script (background.js).
5. Use `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()` to get a picture in background script.
6. Copy it to canvas, shrinking and cropping to desired thumbnail size.
7. Save thumbnail into `chrome.storage.local` as base64.

include2page.js:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var img = list[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, {
        'type': 'imgData',
        'data': {
            x: img.x,
            y: img.y,
            w: img.width,
            h: img.height
        }
    });
}
```

background.js (output to console for simplicity):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "imgData") {
        var imgData = request.data;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "window.scrollTo(0, "+imgData.y+");"});
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: 'png', quality: 100}, function(src) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = 96;
                canvas.height = 96;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var image = new Image();
                image.src = src;
                image.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(image, imgData.x, imgData.y, imgData.w, imgData.h, 0, 0, 96, 96);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png", ""));
                }
        });

});
```

But there's a problem: due to asynchronous nature of extension's functions it doesn't work that well in a continuous cycle, I can get 2-3 thumbnails assign to all of the images, i.e. different images generate are getting one thumbnail.

Maybe there's some simpler solution? Or, if there isn't, how can I replace a cycle?

Comment: Please show us your code. From your text I assume that the problem is a "closure in a loop" problem, but without the code you'll never know

Comment: @devnull69, added basic code to the post.

Comment: Ouch. `captureVisibleTab` is hunting squirrel with a howitzer. If the images are hosted on a specific set of servers, you can add those to your permissions and not suffer from cross-origin woes.

Comment: @Xan, I don't have any access to the servers. Can it be done on client side?

Comment: @user1249568 Certainly - I mean, if the images are not from all around the internet but servers in one domain, you can circumvent same-origin policy in Chrome Extensions by setting permissions.

Comment: @Xan, yeah, from one server. Or, at least, a finite number of servers. Is it done in chrome://flags, or some peculiar permission in extension's manifest?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm not sure this answer will work. If it doesn't, I'd be happy to delete it.*

Instead of using a heavy-handed approach with `captureVisibleTab`, you can try to circumvent cross-origin permissions.

Suppose the images are served from `cdn.images.com`. You need to add that (or a corresponding match pattern if there are many servers) to your manifest:

```
"permissions" : [
   "*://cdn.images.com/*",
   ...
]
```

This enables cross-origin XHR's from the extension's background page.

Then you *should* be able to get the image as a blob with XHR; since this would clear its origin, you can now use it to generate your thumbnail.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/getting-blob-data-from-xhr-request) deals with how to do it.