# Convert Image http get result to Base64 string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I have a request to an url that retrieves an image, it's something like this:

```
this.$http.get(url, { }).success( (data) => { 
    console.log(data)
});
```

The result of console.log(data) is somethis like this

`�PNG ���IHDR����������SZ���sRGB�������gAMA�����a���pHYs�������o�d���IDATx^�t�ֵ=��3333339qb...`

So, how can I convert this result to a base64 string ?

Comment: Uhm, are you making an ajax request to get a binary file ?

Comment: Yes. I need to store the image base64 string content

Comment: If it where me, I'd create a serverside script that gets the image and converts it, that way you circumvent the same-origin policy if that's ever an issue, and serve up Base64 from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) method:

```
console.log(window.btoa(data))
```

Comment: I think i cant achieve my goal with this method. I made a test setting img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + window.btoa(data) and I didn't get the actual image :/

Comment: @mmarques can you give me window.btoa(data) console output? Or maybe you you have some example to show us?

Comment: The output is quite long:
77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAABYAAAAO+/vQgGAAAA77+9U1oLAAAAAXNSR0IA77+977+9HO+/vQAAAARnQU1BAADvv73vv70L77+9YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADu+/vQAADu+/vQHvv71v77+9ZAAA77+977+9SURBVHhe77+977+9B1gc77+977+977+977+977+977+9XXrvv73vv70IVO+/vR0BEu+/vR01JCTUkO+/vUDvv70oAu+/vToI77+9Xu+/vV5t77+9yb1377+9dmI7du+/ve+/ve+/vXEc77+9Ne+/vVPvv73vv73vv71577+9fO+/ve+/vX8/Z3YB77+977+9ee+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vV7vv71977+977+977+977+9bDvvv73vv71777+977+977+977+9aO+/ve+/vQDvv71B77+977+977+9CA8L77+9Su+ ......

Comment: @mmarques maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/getting-blob-data-from-xhr-request) answer will help you