# Blob to base64 encoded DataURI of type image/webp

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, uncaught-exception

Using the following in Firefox or IE (works in Chrome and Opera):

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", imgUrl + ".png", true );
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( xhr.response );
var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );
```

I get:

> uncaught exception: Input must be formatted properly as a base64 encoded
>   DataURI of type image/webp

How can I go from blob to base64 encoded DataURI of type image/webp? I am not very experienced with web JavaScript so apologies is this a simple fix.

Comment: How was the blob originally encoded?

Comment: I've updated my original post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer and Firefox do not support the WebP image format and currently have no plans of supporting it.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=webp
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856375

**Edit:**
Anyway, this question has answers with full examples: [Getting BLOB data from XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8022425/1207156)