# Change to a working video html

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I've researched on how to make a video tag in html work, it says that i need to separate the source, but my problem is what if my source is like this:

```
src="blob:null/725b9d73-403c-41e0-81ef-95effaafd822"
```

While to make a video tag work, the source should be specified like this:

```
<video width="400">
  <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="something.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Any help?

Comment: create a serversite page with the header for the video format and echo the blob there and then refer that page as a url to the source tag

Comment: i was told not to add anything except a single js file... :/

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8022521/4613398