# Cannot perform ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice on a detached ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, web-worker, arraybuffer

I am trying to create `Blob` from `ArrayBuffer` using `.slice()`, because I need to copy `ArrayBuffer` since I know that it will be changed in future (its `byteLength` will be 0) by code which I don't have control/want to change.

```
new Blob([data2.payload.slice()], {type: "video/MP2T"})
```

And I get error

```
Cannot perform ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice on a detached ArrayBuffer
```

on

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

on Windows 7 x64.

Is there any other ways to copy `ArrayBuffer`?
[This way not does actual copy](/a/10101213/3209640), [other ways does not seems to be pretty straightforward](/q/10100798/3209640).

[ArrayBuffer.transfer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer) looks good, but theirs polyfill produce error

```
Source and destination must be ArrayBuffer instances
```

Comment: [Getting BLOB data from XHR request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425)

Comment: @SenJacob `new DataView(arrayBuffer)` way not work, since it not actually copies anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my fault, I has been confused by unclear error message, in this situation nothing can be done since at the moment of `Blob` creating `data2.payload` is already have `byteLength: 0`.

While in usual case with

```
var from = new ArrayBuffer(0);
var to = from.slice();
var to = from.slice(0);
```

`to` will be `ArrayBuffer` with `byteLength: 0`, in this case it's trigger error, because before `data2.payload` passed to my code it is modified in web worker, in order to avoid copying the fragment between main thread and web worker, `data2.payload` ownership is transferred to the worker.

Comment: How is its byteLength set to 0 ?

Comment: ah yes transferables... Forgot about it and yes it explains all your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new Blob([new Uint8Array(data2.payload.slice(0))], {type: "video/MP2T"})`

See it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msxso8hq/1/)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var binaryArray = new Uint8Array(this.response.slice(0)); // use UInt8Array for binary
  var blob = new Blob([binaryArray], { type: "image/png" });
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // create url
  document.getElementById("image").src = imageUrl;
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Tried, same result.

Comment: Try using UInt8Array to create Blob. That worked for me before.

Comment: Tried, it does not copy `ArrayBuffer` now.

Comment: Naaa, ["*6. Let relativeStart be ToInteger(start).*"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraybuffer.prototype.slice) and in [ToInteger(argument)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tointeger) "*1. Let number be ToNumber(argument). [...] 3. If number is NaN, return +0.*" and `Number(undefined)` returns `NaN`, thus `+0` in `ToInteger`, and `Number(null)` returns `0`, so you can also omit the `begin` parameter of `slice(begin [, end])`, it will just default to `0`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it should default to zero. But I could think of just those two reasons only, which have the slightest chances to go wrong. Nice citation..