# When downloading from multiple iFrames, why is IE ignoring subsequent files?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, download, internet-explorer-9

I've seen a few questions asked on this subject, such as:

[How to download multiple files in one shot in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353630/how-to-download-multiple-files-in-one-shot-in-ie)

[Download Multiple Files Without Using Zip File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047645/download-multiple-files-without-using-zip-file)

but they don't seem to work for me.

I'm using a very simple solution and it looks similar to answers to other answers I've seen. The problem is that IE will only download the first report. I have verified that it is making the call to the server multiple time and the server seems to be sending the response, but it seems like IE stops after the first file it receives.

When downloading from multiple iFrames, why is IE ignoring subsequent files?

```
function downloadReports(reportIds) {
    for (var i = 0; i < reportIds.length; i++) {
        var url = "http://page.aspx?id=" + configId + "&reportId=" + reportIds[i];

        setTimeout(function () { $("<iframe src='" + url + "' />").appendTo('body'); }, 500 * i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue. Actually, I'm facing the same issue in IE.

Comment: In our situation, we're seeing this only when downloading non-text files. Trying this out with a .js, .txt or a .json file that returns textual content works just fine. However, downloading anything in a binary format like .doc ends up aborted after the first successful download.

Comment: @Homer, were you able to get this issue fixed?