# Angular js write files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a couple of files from **AWS S3 bucket** using its **SDK** (the files are not public)

Now I need to provide the user an option to choose a directory and store them there.

I know how to store a single file (using BLOB), but these will be **multiple files** (maybe even hundreds), I cannot show the file save dialog box every time.

Please don't suggest I use `aws-cli` `sync` for this.

Comment: Are you searching for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568214/angular-js-download-all-files-button)? If this is not what you mean you might need to zip the files to make it into 1 download.

Comment: somewhat, but not exactly. Its using the BLOB technique which I dont want. It will either keep on showing save dialog for every file, or it will indicate download finished for each file. In my case, the file count can be hundreds.

Comment: Use a library that can zip them, either in browser or server side proxy

Comment: Its coming from AWS S3. I cannot zip it there.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the files and then zip the files using [something like this](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)?

Comment: I'm not sure how memory will be handled. The total size can be in gigabytes. If you've working with that, please give me some example.